# How to print() with python last two words form sentence with space

Tags: python, string, split, slice

How to print() with python last two words form sentence with space? Like "Hello world, there is 200 pcs", I need print: "200 pcs". Thank you so much.

```
sentence = "Hello world, there is 200 pcs"
what_I_need = sentence.split()
what_I_need[-3]
# That prints "is"
print(what_I_need)
# But I need to print "is 200 pcs"
```

Comment: `what_I_need[-3:]`?

Comment: This doesn't make sense:  `what_I_need[-3]`  It evaluates to the third word from the right, but you are discarding the result so it has no effect.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Understanding slice notation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/509211/understanding-slice-notation)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I tell python to take the last 2 words from an email that is in a list like structure but is not a list defined by python because it changes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13482586/how-can-i-tell-python-to-take-the-last-2-words-from-an-email-that-is-in-a-list-l)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Slicing your splitted sentence with `[-2:]` will return the desired output. Try:

```
sentence = "Hello world, there is 200 pcs"
what_I_need = sentence.split()
print(what_I_need[-2:]) # output: ['200', 'pcs']
# or as a string:
print(" ".join(what_I_need[-2:])) # output: 200 pcs
```

Comment: Perfect Gabip, Thank you

Answer (score 1):

```
def get_last_n_words(n:int, sentence:string):
   last_n_Words = ' '.join(sentence.split()[-n:])
   return last_n_words

sentence = "Hello world, there is 200 pcs"
lastThreeWords = get_last_n_words(3, sentence)
# lasthreeWords: "is 200 pcs"
```

Answer (score 0):

this is because that you printed the list in index -3 you should take all element from the end till index -3 so you can use the : operator as  mention before